# Is there a way to force the developer taking care of Object.Equals over-ridden function in case of adding new properties?

Tags: c#, .net, attributes

I'm designing a class in which probably some other properties will be added later on. I also overrode the Object.Equals() function. I need to to notify the developers to take care of this function in case of adding new properties. Is there a way to do that? Maybe some attributes? So that if one adds new properties, he/she gets warned that the Equals() function is obsolete?

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/How-To-Write-a-C%23-Analyzer-and-Code-Fix or simply write a Unit Test that fills all the public properties  with some data (probably using Reflection), then calls `Equals()` with the appropriate assertions. Once any of the properties isn't taken into account in the `Equals()` implementation, your assertion should fail